# How do I bind a handler to each item in the list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li name="one">1</li>
  <li name="two">2</li>
  <li name="three">3</li>
  <li name="four">4</li>
  <li name="five">5</li>
  <li name="six">6</li>
</ul>
```

Each element is necessary to prescribe -

```
 onMouseOver={() => this.hover(event.target.getAttribute('name'))}
 onMouseOut={() => this.hover(false)}
```

There are a lot of elements, is it possible to specify these handlers without prescribing them to each element?

Comment: Consider [*event delegation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use map, define your array of object first.

```js
const allData = [
  {key: 1, name:'one'},
  {key: 2, name:'two'},
  {key: 3, name:'three'},
  {key: 4, name:'four'}
]

allData.map((data) => {
  <li 
    name=data.name
    onMouseOver={() => this.hover(event.target.getAttribute('name'))}
    onMouseOut={() => this.hover(false)}
  >
    data.key
  </li>
})
```